# adding values in certain columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new to R.  In a data frame, I wanted to create a new column #21 that is equal to the sum of column #1 to #20,row by row.

I knew I could do

```
df$Col21<-df$Col1+df$Col2+.....+df$Col20
```

But is there a more concise expression?

Also, can I achieve this if using column names not numbers? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is rowSums:

```
df$Col21 = rowSums(df[,1:20])
```

should do the trick, and with names:

```
df$Col21 = rowSums(df[,paste("Col", 1:20, sep="")])
```

With leading zeros and 3 digits, try:

```
df$Col21 = rowSums(df[,sprintf("Col%03d", 1:20, sep="")])
```

Comment: +1. For interactive use `subset` would also work: `rowSums(subset(df, select = Col1:Col20))`.

Answer (score 0):

I find the `dplyr` functions for column selection very intuitive, like `starts_with(), ends_with(), contains(),  matches()` and `num_range()`:

```
df <- as.data.frame(replicate(20, runif(10)))
names(df) <- paste0("Col", 1:20)
library(dplyr)
# e.g.
summarise_each(df, funs(sum), starts_with("Col")) 
# or
rowSums(select(df, contains("8")))
```